# How to lock Deluge's configuration files to prevent their modification?

Tags: configuration, bittorrent, lock, deluge, torrent-client

I'm setting up a seedbox for 3 users on Ubuntu Server 15.04. Each user runs his copy of deluged and deluge-web and has its home directory where deluge's configuration files reside. I optimized the files for speed and now I'd like to lock them to prevent them from any change (so that the users can't change config with deluge-web ui or deluge client).

What I tried is:

I chowned the files by root (and removed world permissions) but then they just get deleted and swapped by a new configuration file by deluged. I also gave them +i attribute with chattr so that even root cannot modify/delete the files without removing the "i" flag but then deluged just creates a new conf file: core.conf.new which can be modified by deluge-web ui.

How do I lock the files. Is there any other way to prevent users from modifying deluge's configuration? For now, I'd like to lock core.conf and ltconfig.conf in every users directory and force deluge to use these config files but if there's any other way I'd be happy to hear it.

Comment: I don't know about Deluge, but if it's making a new config file and using that instead of the locked one, I'd say you're not looking at a simple Linux permissions issue.

Comment: A method would be to create a script that keeps on copying back the default config and that deletes the "*.new" versions. In theory you could check the file for differences and if there are also restart the daemon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deluge only reads the conf files on startup so although you can prevent settings being saved to disk they will still be applied in code, until next restart. A file such as `core.conf.new` does not mean that the application has updated `core.conf`, it is simply a temporary file.

The only option would be to modify the ConfigManager code or use the development version of Deluge that has multi-user support but there is no time-scale for release.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I guess the only option I have now is to learn to install and configure rtorrent/rutorrent.

Answer (score 0):

Although I do use deluge with multiple users, I run multiple `deluged` instances. Each instance uses its own directory and `core.conf`. To do this, when launching `deluged`, you want to include the option to use a specific `core.conf`. For example:

```
/usr/bin/deluged -d -c /storage/delgsvr10 -L warning -l /storage/delgsvr10/deluged.log
```

This command launches `deluged` with options of -d -c -L -l. Run `deluged -h` to get the definition of each option. Note when specifying the configuration file you just specify the directory, not the file. This works on version 1.3.6 at least.